# ansible register on template is not working

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to restart `nginx` in my `ansible` playbook if I changed the configuration. The configuration copy is done via template.

```
- name: update nginx.conf
  template: src=../templates/nginx_global_conf.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  sudo: yes
  register: nginx_conf
- name: restart nginx if needed
  shell: service nginx restart
  when: nginx_conf.changed
```

Even if I'm getting:

```
TASK: [webapp | update nginx.conf] ********************************************
changed: [IPADDRESS]
```

I ALWAYS get:

```
TASK: [webapp | restart nginx if needed] **************************************
skipping: [IPADDRESS]
```

Tried also instead of shell:

```
action: service name=nginx state=restarted enabled=yes
```

It is not the problem. The register that isn't signalling is...

Comment: Some recommendations. Always use `nginx_conf | changed` instead of `nginx_conf.changed`. And use an appropriate module whenever possible. Only use shell/command when there is no module for what you want to do. But that won't help here. Did you try to debug your registered value? `- debug: var= nginx_conf`. An alternative for the registered value would be to use a handler instead: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Comment: You should run Ansible with `-v` switch to debug the issue. You should see the actual value of the variable in the run.

Comment: When running with -v I'm getting 
TASK: [webapp | update nginx.conf] ********************************************
changed: [192.168.10.135] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "a657b88cbe76abce4a2a409b177631427347f267", "dest": "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "md5sum": "94f073a0116c76455540b73384a5b668", "mode": "0644", "owner": "root", "size": 1055, "src": "/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455648101.98-37044083565097/source", "state": "file", "uid": 0}

Don't see nginx_conf in there

Answer (score 1):

OK. Apparently I had the same `nginx_conf` in a different yml I included.
Keeping the question here because there are quite some good tips.
Thanks to all the helpers